# Running arbitrary SQL queries in Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I've just been tasked with automating a reporting task at work. Previously, someone would run large, arbitrary `SELECT`s on a MySQL database using a GUI tool, then use that same tool to export the results to CSV. Now I want to write a Ruby script to do this.

I know about FasterCSV in Ruby, but as far as SQL queries, I've only used ActiveRecord, where you're generally not writing the queries but using models and associations. The last time I wrote out complete SQL in code was when I coded PHP.

What's the most straightforward way to do this sort of thing in Ruby? **Should** I use ActiveRecord?

Comment: LOL, I'm haven't done complex sql since php too.

Comment: As a note, FasterCSV became the standard library's csv module in 1.9. If you are using 1.8, you would need to `gem install fastercsv` to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a complex application, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using ActiveRecord.  Especially since you are already comfortable with it.

If you are writing a quick script and don't want to bother with ActiveRecord, you should also check out the [mysql](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql) and [mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gems.

Comment: It's a quick script, and yeah, mysql2 looks good. I really just want to drop the existing queries right into my script, so if I can then iterate over the results as hashes, that's pretty great. Someday I may make this more complex, but for now the idea is just to write a script, set it to a cron job, and move on.

Comment: The other thing I like about mysql2 is that I know we're already using it in our Rails apps.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org). It has great [documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html), [active development](http://sequel.heroku.com/), a thriving and helpful community, and it is (IMHO) simpler and better than ActiveRecord, *especially* for simple use cases like you appear to have.

You might want to start by reading the [README](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html), [Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) and [Sequel for SQL Users](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html).

Comment: +1 for Sequel. I did some ActiveRecord work outside of Rails, and, while I got it working ok, I found Sequel to be much easier and more user-friendly. It's my ORM of choice for Ruby. I like how it is easy to use it with models of the tables, like ActiveRecord does, or to work with datasets, or with raw SQL. Sequel stays out of the way in each scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that in reporting engines you end up with complex queries processing large amounts of data and ORMs like ActiveRecord just don't cut it.  Unless your reports are really simple, I think you'll want to use raw SQL (with a tool like Sequel) or call stored procedures.